# Excel - copy values according to transposition

Tags: excel, transpose

I have a table on an Excel sheet formatted like this

[image: Table]

I managed to transpose column A and B so I have this

[image: Table Transposed]

and I'd finally like to have something like this

[image: Table with values]

Does anyone have an idea what formula to use in order to achieve this ?

I have a looong formula mixing INDEX, MATCH, IF but that doesn't seem to be good...

Thanks a lot

Comment: Looks like SUMIFS should work.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. Not sure I understand what you mean here..i'm not that good in Excel formulas and macros :-P . SUMIFS, will give the sum of numbers according to some criterias. Here, i don't want to to sum values up but reorganise the columns and put the value corresponding to a header and row in a cell. Isn't it ?   Also the headers and rows will be dynamic so values will readapt according to a filter on the sheet.

Comment: If you have the setup shown in your second screenshot, SUMIFS can get you to the third screenshot.

Comment: Or use a pivot table.

Comment: using a pivot table won't work cause the table is an extract of a SharePoint list that uses choices fields. But I used SUMIFS as you recommended and i'm almost there, i wrote SUMIFS($C$1:$C$5,$A$1:$A$5,A1,$B$1:$B$5,B1)... this works for the first value then...well the criterias (A1 and B1) are not dynamic so i get the wrong values. but i see if i correctly update these criterias, i get the right value at the right place..so the question now is...how can i update this criteria dynamically ? thanks !!

Comment: `=SUMIFS($C$1:$C$5,$A$1:$A$5,$A1,$B$1:$B$5,B$1)`... - but I don't understand the second part of your comment.

Comment: hmm...i updated according to what you just wrote , that give me 1 for Aa-Ba and then...all the rest is 0. So that's still not good.  What i meant about the dynamic value is exactly the issue i have now the "0" everywhere else.

Comment: Oh sorry - you shouldn't use `$A1` or `B$1` but refer to your *new* headers and row labels in the new table.

Comment: OK !!! I have it !!!  My transposed table starting from I1 to M1 and H2 to H6 the correct answer  is :    =SUMIFS($C$1:$C$5,$A$1:$A$5,INDEX($A$1:$A$5,MATCH(I$1,$A$1:$A$5,0)),$B$1:$B$5,INDEX($B$1:$B$5,MATCH($H2,$B$1:$B$5,0)))    We did it !! thanks a lot for your help !! :-)